# Laravel: How to use the blade templates In Mail::send() without using third party service provider?

Tags: laravel

I want send the mails using the Laravel Mail Class with blade templates and without using the third party service provider like mailgun etc...

Answer (score 0):

you just need to set your `.env` file with the details of your SMTP server login credentials:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=<your smtp server>
MAIL_PORT=<25/465/587>
MAIL_USERNAME=<smtp user>
MAIL_PASSWORD=<smtp pass>
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=<tls/ssl>
```